# Java Stream or Map Merge by key

Tags: java, java-stream

What would be the simplest way to merge Map key values like keys "55", "55004", "550009", "550012" **into one key: "55"** and a sum of all those values().

I'm trying to think of ways to use containsKey or trimming the key. It's very hard to think about this.

Maybe a flatMap to flatten the map and reduce.

```
@Test
public void TestM(){
        Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap();
        map1.put("55", 3453.34);
        map1.put("55001", 5322.44);
        map1.put("55003", 10112.44);
        map1.put("55004", 15555.74);
        map1.put("77", 1000.74); // instead of 1000 it should be ~1500
        map1.put("77004", 444.74);
        map1.put("77003", 66.74);
        // in real example I'll need "77" and "88" and "101" etc. 
        // All of which has little pieces like 77004, 77006

        Map<String,Double> SumMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();

        SumMap = map1.entrySet().stream().map
                   (e->e.getValue()).reduce(0d, Double::sum);
       // INCORRECT
       // REDUCE INTO ONE KEY startsWith 55

        System.out.println("Map: " + SumMap);
       // RESULT should be :
       // Map<String, Double> result = { "55": TOTAL }
       // real example might be "77": TOTAL, "88": TOTAL, "101": TOTAL         
       //(reducing away the "77004", "88005" etc.)
}
```

Basically this code reduces and rolls subitem totals into a bigger key.

Comment: @tobias_k added it to the comments at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you could use `Collectors.groupingBy`.

It requires Function which would allow us decide which elements belong to same group. Such function for elements from same group should always return same value which will be used as key in resulting map. In your case it looks like you want to group elements with same first two characters stored in key, which suggest mapping to `substring(0,2)`.

When we already have way to determine which elements belong to same group, we can now specify how we want map to collect them. By default it collects them in list so we have `key->[elemnt0, element1, ...]` mapping.
But we can specify your own way of handling elements from same group by providing our own Collector. Since we want to create sum of values we can use `Collectors.summingDouble(mappingToDouble)`.

DEMO:

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("661", 123d);
map1.put("662", 321d);
map1.put("55", 3453.34);
map1.put("55001", 5322.44);
map1.put("55003", 10112.44);
map1.put("55004", 15555.74);

Map<String, Double> map = map1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                entry -> entry.getKey().substring(0, 2), 
                Collectors.summingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
            )
        );

System.out.println(map);
```

Output: `{66=444.0, 55=34443.96}`